# Is Bridge Edge Loops in Sverchok possible?

Tags: python, scripting, sverchok

Is there something like Bridge Edge Loops in Sverchok (possible)? Or can I perhaps easily (using a ScriptNode) call LoopTool's Bridge, Circle, Curve, Space, etc.?

Comment: Bridge Edge Loops, while not an exact analogy - the simplest case of bridging two loops can be done using UVConnect (verts + edge count have to match up). I don't think you want to mess with triggering LoopTools operators from ScriptNode.

Comment: But that's always a straight, shortest way connection then, isn't it? So, no number of cuts, interpolation (Surface, Path) and Smoothness?

Comment: UVConnection indeed does not follow the contour of any surrounding faces (as it only knows about incoming verts), and doesn't offer loopcuts on the result. Closer examination of LoopTools code will show you that it's not designed in a way that can "trivially" be called by a ScriptNode. (I wrote ScriptNode...so i say this with a birds-eye view) . ---- With a certain amount of coercion of the LoopTools code specific results can be achieved --- posting a screenshot of an example desired before/after could help..

Comment: I know my way around in RhinoCommon, but not in Blender. I thought, every add-on perhaps needs to be implemented in a way that makes it easy for other add-ons to call their functionality. (Which would make sense, of course.) Thank you!

Comment: marcus , consider accepting the answer or augment your question if my answer doesn't suffice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a less obvious alternative if you want to add faces / edges to skin a sequence of edge loops and interpolate the shapes.

Some of this layout exists just to generate the sequence of edge loops (shapes), the real work is done by *Vector interpolate MK2* and *UVConnect*. This layout works under the reasonable assumption that the number of verts in each loop is identical and that the indices of consecutive shapes already line up (so there's no excessive twisting).

[image]

Here's a more practical example for naval architecture, using *BezierCurve* input

[image]

Here the Bezier Object is made from a certain number of "sub curves/splines", each spline in that example is represented by 13 vertices. The Objects-in Node just makes a flat list of the resulting vertices, that's why we List-Split on size 13 to get the individual *spline data*.

blend of the hull 
[image]

Comment: It is always so much easier to have something working as a starting point. Can you perhaps share the file here?

Comment: sure. see above